# Can't install rmagick, pkg-config: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, osx-mavericks, rmagick

I'm trying to install rmagick on my [Mac OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) machine. However. I get this error

```
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 41: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 47: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 50: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.
```

The lines 41,17,50,53 in Magick-config are

```
--cflags)
  pkg-config --cflags MagickCore
  ;;
--cxxflags)
  pkg-config --cflags MagickCore
  ;;
--cppflags)
  pkg-config --cflags MagickCore
  ;;
--ldflags)
  pkg-config --libs MagickCore
  ;;
--libs)
  pkg-config --libs MagickCore
  ;;
```

I installed ImageMagick with `brew install imagemagick --build-from-source` and before running `gem install rmagick`, I set the path to MagickCore.pc with `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/lib/pkgconfig` and the path to Wand.h with `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/include/ImageMagick-6/`.

This worked for the Wand, but not for MagickCore, as I still get `pkg-config: command not found`.

I use Ruby 1.9.3p545 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.16.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to install `pkg-config` or updated `PATH` to include it's location. Building from source expects this utility to be on the system.

Comment: `pkg-config` already came installed with homebrew. what `PATH` do you want me to update?

Comment: Are you sure `pkg-config` is in the location you specified?  Check with `which pkg-config`.  For me, it's in `/usr/local/bin/pkg-config` though I am using OSX 10.7.5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reinstalling `pkg-config` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 66):

I had the same issue with Rmagick after upgrading to Maverick. This solved it:

```
brew uninstall pkg-config
brew install pkg-config
brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config
```

Comment: In my case, `brew uninstall pkg-config` failed so I just ran `brew install pkg-config` and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Yesssss!!!! After several hours of unsuccessfully trying all other StackOverflow solutions, this FINALLY let me install the rmagick gem. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`brew install pkg-config` fixed this for me.