# NPM fails installing zmq on OSX 10.9.5

Tags: node.js, npm, osx-mavericks, zeromq

I'm getting this error:

```
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config libzmq --libs' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
```

I've tried upgrading nodejs to 5.1.0.

I've tried downgrading nodejs to 4.2.2.

I've tried completely removing nodejs manually then re-installing 4.2.2 and trying again.

I've tried the removal script here: 
https://gist.github.com/brock/5b1b70590e1171c4ab54

Then re-installing each version and trying again.

I've tried downgrading to zeromq 4.0.7.

No luck.

Here's the complete error:

```
localhost:~ user$ npm install zmq
/
> zmq@2.14.0 install /Users/user/node_modules/zmq
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config libzmq --libs' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "zmq"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! zmq@2.14.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.14.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23957018/275491

Comment: I just tried it.  There error now has changed to: Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Comment: zeromq version 4.1.3 configure file references the PKG_CONFIG_PATH twice:  Line 682 & 811.  Both are blank.  I'm uncertain as to how to proceed?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/283  I also highly recommend [Node Version Manager(nvm)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).  I've been having trouble with npm 3, and it makes it easy to restore a fresh install of node.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked...

install ***zmq*** using *brew* : `brew install zmq`

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.0.4/lib/pkgconfig/`

`sudo visudo`

add the line `Defaults env_keep += "PKG_CONFIG_PATH"`

`sudo npm install zmq`

Comment: Note for anyone trying to install the bitcore library on OSX High Sierra - these steps worked perfectly and i was able to `npm install zmq` without sudo and then was able to `npm install -S bitcore` perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it:

**Step 1:**

```
brew install zmq
```

**Step 2:**

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.2.5/lib/pkgconfig/
```

(Note: zeromq Version 4.2.5 in path above will need to be changed to whatever version you installed)

**Step 3:**

`sudo visudo` 
and add 
    `Defaults env_keep += "PKG_CONFIG_PATH"`

**Step 4:**

In package.json > dependencies, add:

```
"zmq": "^2.15.3"
```

**Step 5:**

Run `yarn` or `npm install`