# pkg-config: command not found during compile, but pkg-config installed

Tags: c, macos, pkg-config, guile

**Update:** I got it working, the problem has something to do with the fact that I was running it through emacs. I ran the makefile from the command line instead, and pkg-config ran. After adding the path to guile-2.0.pc with `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig` everything compiled and ran OK. Still won't compile through emacs but I don't want to deal with that.

I am trying to compile a C program but received a "pkg-config: command not found" error, but am pretty sure pkg-config is installed.

Below is the MAKEFILE

```
# Use GCC, if you have it installed.
CC=gcc

# Tell the C compiler where to find <libguile.h>
CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags guile-2.0`

# Tell the linker what libraries to use and where to find them.
LIBS=`pkg-config --libs guile-2.0`

simple-guile: simple-guile.o
${CC} simple-guile.o ${LIBS} -o simple-guile

simple-guile.o: test.c
${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} test.c
```

Below is the error message (re: second error, I think if I can resolve this issue the libguile.h file will be found)

```
make 
gcc -c `pkg-config --cflags guile-2.0` test.c
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
test.c:2:11: fatal error: 'libguile.h' file not found
 #include <libguile.h> 
      ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [simple-guile.o] Error 1
```

I installed pkg-config by

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Installation appears successful?...

```
Jeffs-iMac:~ Jeff$ which pkg-config
/opt/local/bin/pkg-config
```

If it's relevant, this should be the same directory in which guile is located:

```
Jeffs-iMac:~ Jeff$ which guile
/opt/local/bin/guile
```

Am using OS X 10.11.3

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling  pkg-config per: [Can't install rmagick, pkg-config: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684133/cant-install-rmagick-pkg-config-command-not-found)

I'm a novice programmer, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Won't fix the cause, but if you want to get going quickly you could just use the full path of the executable (`/opt/local/bin/pkg-config`)

Comment: this line: `CC=gcc` will pickup the first executable found using the PATH environment variable.  That may not be the one your interested in.  Suggest: `CC := /usr/lib/gcc`  BTW: when only using the `=` operator, the macro will be re-evaluated each time it is referenced.  However, using the `:=` operator means the macro will only be evaluated once, no matter how many times it is referenced.

Comment: looking at the posted makefile:  Do you know that all lines below a target must be indented via tab character?  This is not being reflected in the posted makefile

Comment: the `pkg-config` should be in `/usr/bin`.   the fact that it is in /opt/local/bin` indicate that install was not done correctly

Comment: @user3629249 - nonsense. Nothing outside of OS X system installations should be attempting to install in `/usr/bin`, and no one should attempt to copy / link such 3rd party utilities there in a (misguided) sense of expediency.

Comment: "something to do with the fact" isn't reproducable this is too localized